# ColdFusion Dates before a date

Tags: coldfusion

I seem to have a brain fart here. I'm trying to show all users that were entered in a database 14 days, or more, before today's date. For some reason I either get everyone or no one, but not the ones I need. Here is what I have. Please tell me where I am going wrong. Thank You!

```
<CFSET TodaysDate = #DateFormat (Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy")#>
<CFSET CheckDate = #DateFormat(TodaysDate-14,"mm-dd-yyyy")#>

<cfquery name="getUser" datasource="DNS_Test">
    select *
    from   Login
    where  DateEntered <= #CheckDate#
</cfquery>


<cfoutput> 
<cfloop QUERY="getUser">
   #getUser.LastName#, #getUser.FirstName# <br>
<cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Dateformat returns a string, not a date object.  Change your 1st cfset to CreateDate(year(now()), month(now()), day(now())).  Then read Chris's answer.

Comment: It is because you are passing in a totally different value than you are thinking. `#CheckDate#` actually evaluates to a number: `-2020`. ie The month number - day - year, ie `11-17-2014 == -2020`. The reason the query does not throw an error is that date/time columns are represented as numbers internally. So your current query is actually comparing two numbers. However, it obviously is NOT using the date (ie number) you are thinking ... To avoid these kinds of issues, you should be using date objects and `cfqueryparam` as Chris suggested.

Comment: *Dateformat returns a string* Yes, but it actually gets converted to a number, due to the lack of quotes. So the actual query they are executing is: `.. where  DateEntered <= -2020`. Hence the wrong results.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but .. no need to use both cfoutput *and* a query cfloop. Simply use `<cfoutput query="..">`. Also, you can get rid of the # signs in the `cfset` statements. They are redundant.

Answer (score 14):

You'll want to use `DateAdd()`.

Example: Never `use select *`, instead use column names... also investigate using `<cfqueryparam>`

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName
FROM Login
WHERE DateEntered <= <cfqueryparam value="#DateAdd( 'd', -14, now() )#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_DATE">
```

Comment: I wish I could +1 again for telling OP not to use `select *`

Comment: *investigate using cfqueryparam* +1. Definitely. The example above is the correct way to handle dates in a query. ie Use date objects, not strings. Also, use cfquerparam with the proper type ie "cf_sql_date" or "cf_sql_timestamp".

Comment: Nice query param Chris. +1

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to do the calculation in SQL. For example, in SQL Server:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName
FROM Login
WHERE DateEntered <= CONVERT(date, 
   DateAdd(dd, <cfqueryparam value="-14" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">, 
   getDate())
   )
```

Some adjustments may be needed if DateEntered has hh:mm:ss

Comment: I'm surprised this has negative 2 votes currently. Technically I suppose it doesn't answer the *ColdFusion* question, but it is certainly a valid suggestion, and one I'd make as well. Not saying I'd use it instead, but I'd at least mention it.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but there is a slight problem with this answer.  GetDate() returns a date and a time which could prove problematic.  If I were going to use this approach, I would cast getDate() to a date.

Comment: Sorry but -1. Do not use functions on a column. It will prevent the database from utilizing indexes. Besides, there is no need to convert the column values to dates. Just cast the *constant* to the desired value and the comparison operator will take of the rest.

Comment: Updated answer to not cast

Comment: Thank you for your help and expertise. This is the first time I'm using Stack and will be coming back. I'm sure I'll have another question soon.